# Insert multiple same input name field codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**id    userid    fldWorkHistoryCompanyName    fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate 

 1          1                      abc company                               2016.12.03

2          1                       def company                                2017.12.03

3          1                            ghi company                                2018.12.03

4          2                            ask company                                2014.12.03**

```html
<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Privet Limited 1" >

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[]" >

<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Privet Limited 2" >

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[]" >

<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Privet Limited 3" >

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[]" >
```

how to insert multiple name filed in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert multiple input text values in database using single name.

You can make a form with method POST and put these fields into form and when you submit the button you can put the action into your controller.

In the controller, you can do

```
$history[] = $_Post['fldWorkHistoryCompanyName'];

foreach ($history as $key => $value) {
  // make insert query and your value is in the $value variable.
}
```

OR

If you have active records then you can to do this:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'userid' => '1' ,
      'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName' => 'Name' ,
      'fldWorkHistoryJoinedDate' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'userid' => '2' ,
      'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName' => 'Another Name' ,
      'fldWorkHistoryJoinedDate' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$fldWorkHistoryCompanyName = $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryCompanyName');
foreach ($fldWorkHistoryCompanyName as $value) {
    $data = array(
        'field_name' => $value
    );
    $this->db->insert('tableName',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution :

```
$i = 0
Foreach($fldWorkHistoryCompanyName as $key=>$value)
{
    $data[$i]['fldWorkHistoryCompanyName'] = $value;
    $data[$i]['fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate'] = $fldWorkHistoryJoiniedDate[$key];
    $i++;
}      
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name',$data);
```